# How do I go about asking for a job on another team?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, internship

I'm an intern right now and my term is almost up. Here towards the end of my internship I've started doing some work for another team based on my interests. I initially met with the manager on that team last week for coffee and we talked about a range of stuff including my long-term interests before she gave me some work to do. During that meeting she told me about a post-grad position that they're hiring for; I'm done with school in June so I'm definitely interested. I really like them too -- today she invited me to join the team for lunch and it was a good time.

Basically it feels like they might be interested but I'm not sure the best strategy for approaching this. Should I straight up send an email expressing my interest? I've only done a little bit of work for them and like I said my internship is about to be over, so I didn't have THAT much time to get to know them. But I'm almost out of time and think I should make a move.

What steps should I take to show them that I'm interested in joining their team?

Comment: So when you say "I didn't have THAT much time to get to know them" does this mean you aren't certain you want to join their team?  It's not clear whether you are worried about the proper corporate procedure or still deciding if you want to pull the trigger.

Answer (score 6):

You are overthinking this a bit. They have been lunching with you and told you about an opening they have. They definitely want you to apply, I would just ask what the application process is for the said position.

Answer (score 4):

> Basically it feels like they might be interested but I'm not sure the
>   best strategy for approaching this. Should I straight up send an email
>   expressing my interest?

No.

Walk over, ask for a few minutes of her time, and talk to her in person.

Express your interest. Indicate your availability. Ask if you could be considered for the position. If she indicates "Yes", then ask how to start the process of applying.

Comment: Usually a team lunch during formal/informal interviews means they like you and want to figure out if you are a cultural fit. So most of the hard work is already done by the manager in question. All you have to do, just like Joe said, is tell her you want the job. This might impact your chances of negotiating a strong starting package, as she already knows you want to work for her.